# Where clause that excludes specific combination of values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that I want to exclude a specific set of combinations. In this case I do NOT want records where BOTH the round id and name match the values I specify.

Unfortunately my query excludes any result that has one OR the other (despite the parenthesis). I noticed I only get unexpected results within the parenthesis when using '!=' for both variables (when one or both use '=' it respects both conditions as expected).

Can someone please help me adjust the query so the only results excluded are those that match both criteria? An explanation of why what I'm doing is wrong would also be appreciated. (I had to change table names but hopefully it's still readable)

```
DECLARE @rn VARCHAR(20) = 'Value 1'
DECLARE @round NVARCHAR(15) = 'Value 2'

SELECT DISTINCT rfr.RFId, r2.Name ,dc.Code, r.RoundId
FROM review.RF rf
JOIN review.RFRound rfr ON rfr.RFId = rf.RFId AND ISNULL(rfr.IsDeleted,0)=0
JOIN review.Round r ON r.RoundAutoId = rfr.RoundAutoId
JOIN dc.DeficiencyCode dc ON dc.DeficiencyCodeId = rf.DeficiencyCodeId
JOIN review.SR sr ON sr.SRId = rf.SRId
JOIN reftype.Review r2 ON r2.ReviewId = sr.ReviewId
WHERE (r.RoundId != @round AND r2.Name != @rn) --it basically ignores my parenthesis
```

Comment: Please show sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this case I do NOT want records where BOTH the round id and name match the values I specify.

Change `!=` to `=` for both conditions and precede your parenthesis with `not`

```
declare @rn varchar(20) = 'Value 1';
declare @round nvarchar(15) = 'Value 2';

select distinct 
    rfr.RFId
  , r2.name
  , dc.Code
  , r.RoundId
from review.RF rf
  inner join review.RFRound rfr
    on rfr.RFId = rf.RFId and isnull(rfr.IsDeleted, 0) = 0
  inner join review.Round r
    on r.RoundAutoId = rfr.RoundAutoId
  inner join dc.DeficiencyCode dc
    on dc.DeficiencyCodeId = rf.DeficiencyCodeId
  inner join review.SR sr
    on sr.SRId = rf.SRId
  inner join reftype.Review r2
    on r2.ReviewId = sr.ReviewId
where not (
      r.RoundId = @round 
    and r2.name = @rn
  )
```

To only include results that additional match only one of the parameters, add

```
 and (
      r.RoundId = @round 
    or r2.name = @rn
  )
```

It may (or may not) help to think about your `where` conditions in terms of [Logic gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate)

The premise of your question is your are applying a `nand` logic, which is short for `not and`, which translates to `not ( condition and condition )`.

NAND:

```
+---+---+----------+
| A | B | A NAND B |
+---+---+----------+
| 0 | 0 |        1 |
| 0 | 1 |        1 |
| 1 | 0 |        1 |
| 1 | 1 |        0 |
+---+---+----------+
```

Comment: sorry I messed up the most important part of the explanation

Comment: @JMariña Updated

Comment: Thank you, that worked. If you can point me to a resource that explains why the 'not' is appropriate it would be appreciated!

Comment: @JMariña Updated with a reference and short explanation of `nand`

Comment: Thank you again, this is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

remove '!' from your where condition

```
DECLARE @rn VARCHAR(20) = 'Value 1'
DECLARE @round NVARCHAR(15) = 'Value 2'

SELECT DISTINCT rfr.RFId, r2.Name ,dc.Code, r.RoundId
FROM review.RF rf
JOIN review.RFRound rfr ON rfr.RFId = rf.RFId AND ISNULL(rfr.IsDeleted,0)=0
JOIN review.Round r ON r.RoundAutoId = rfr.RoundAutoId
JOIN dc.DeficiencyCode dc ON dc.DeficiencyCodeId = rf.DeficiencyCodeId
JOIN review.SR sr ON sr.SRId = rf.SRId
JOIN reftype.Review r2 ON r2.ReviewId = sr.ReviewId
WHERE r.RoundId = @round 
  AND r2.Name = @rn
```